# How to switch to a different xdg-desktop-portal to have a different file picker?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome3, d-bus, xdg

I am using nemo as my default file and desktop manager using [How to set Nemo as the default file manager in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446372/598062)

In brief it looks like:

```
sudo apt install nemo
xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

And `~/.config/autostart/nemo-desktop.desktop` file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Nemo
Comment=Start Nemo desktop at log in
Exec=nemo-desktop
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
NoDisplay=true
```

The refered answer suggest using Desktop Icons NG (DING) extension and the following:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.ding use-nemo true
```

However, that replace the `nemo-destop`, which will break my UX, so I refrained from it.

Everything is alright till now except the **file picker** or **file chooser**.

The Gtk / GIO FileChooser:

- Add some extra folders in Places Sidebar which I do not want.
- There is no address bar in the file picker (I know i can press <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> to get the address bar, but I want it by default).

I would like to have something like (lookswise):

```
zenity --file-selection
zenity --file-selection --save
kdialog --getopenfilename
kdialog --getsavefilename
```

I found that xdg-desktop-portal is the new tool to do this sort of stuff (please correct me if i am wrong).

There are some posts which suggest using `GTK_USE_PORTAL=1`, `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE`. I am not optimistic about it. What does `GTK_USE_PORTAL=1` mean? Here, `1` is a hard coded value, why not `2` or `3`. How is it processed? Again if I use `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE` in a gnome system, then will it not break stuff?

Is there a simpler way to **tell gnome that use file picker from X portal**?

I found the following files so there are dbus interfaces for file picker.

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.gtk4.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml
```

In my machine, I also found multiple xdg-desktop-portal

```
$ ls -la /usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/portals
.rw-r--r-- 100 root 23 Mar 14:48 gnome-keyring.portal
.rw-r--r--  99 root 20 Mar 02:25 gnome-shell.portal
.rw-r--r-- 548 root 18 Oct  2022 gnome.portal
.rw-r--r-- 495 root 29 Nov  2022 gtk.portal
.rw-r--r-- 664 root  6 Jul 12:27 kde.portal
```

So, what is the easiest way to switch to a different xdg-desktop-portal to have a different file picker? (I am open to any suggestions to address my issue as long as the file picker is **changed or modified** to address my needs, i am not fixated at `xdg-desktop-portal`, i just have a feeling that it is the tool for the job, i might be absolutely wrong).